# number of seeds in Lagged fibonacci Random number generator

Tags: random, cuda, parallel-processing

Can any one tell me the number of seeds in lagged fibonacci random number generator as a function of typical lagged fibonacci parameters, I would really appreciate a diagram to illustrate the working of the random number generator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The design and properties of Fibonacci generators are discussed in the widely cited paper by [Brent](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.4.1867&rep=rep1&type=pdf), and it includes an overview of implementation on a vector supercomputer of the time. This paper forms the basis of the boost::random Fibonacci generators, so you can see what a modern implementation looks like by inspecting the boost source.

I am not quite sure what this question has to do with cuda or parallel programming, though.

Comment: He doesnt mention anything about the seeds there, LF RNG is mostly used for random number generation in CUDA as well as parallel programming